# $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space iff $(X,d')$ is a complete metric space.

Tags: real-analysis

I recently got asked this question on an exam and I wasn't able to give a solution.

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and we define
 $$d'(x,y)= \frac {d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$$
(I've already proved that $(X,d')$ is a metric space.)

Prove that $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space iff $(X,d')$ is a complete metric space.

Comment: Hint: the two metrics define the same topology and the same set of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Hint: notice that $\frac{d}{1+d} \leq d$, so if a sequence is $d$-Cauchy then it is $d'$-Cauchy. On the other hand, if $d' \leq c<1$ then (after some algebra) $d \leq \frac{c}{1-c}$. In particular if $d' \leq 1/2$ then $d \leq 2d'$. So if a sequence is $d'$-Cauchy then it is $d$-Cauchy. Now check that limits coincide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see that $d' = {d \over 1+ d} \le {d \over 1} = d$, hence a $d$-Cauchy sequence is a $d'$-Cauchy sequence.

Note that if $d'(x,y) \neq 1$, then since $d'(x,y) = { d(x,y) \over 1 + d(x,y) }$, then $d(x,y) = { d'(x,y) \over 1 - d'(x,y) }$.

Now suppose $x_n$ is a $d'$-Cauchy sequence, and choose $N$ such that if $m,n \ge N$, then $d'(x_n,x_m) \le {1 \over 2}$. Then for $m,n \ge N$, we have
$d(x,y) \le  2 d'(x,y)$ and so the sequence is a $d$-Cauchy sequence.

If $(X,d)$ is complete, and $x_n$ is $d$-Cauchy, then there is some $x$ such that $d(x,x_n) \to 0$. Since $d' \le d$, it follows that $d'(x,x_n) \to 0$ and hence $(X,d')$ is complete.

Similarly, if $(X,d')$ is complete, and $x_n$ is $d'$-Cauchy, then there is some $x$ such that $d'(x,x_n) \to 0$. Choose $N$ such that if $n \ge N$
then $d'(x,x_n) \le {1 \over 2}$, then we have $d(x,x_n) \le 2 d'(x,x_n)$ and
so $d(x,x_n) \to 0$ and hence $(X,d)$ is complete.

Comment: One must also show that the $d$-limit of a sequence is the same as the $d'$-limit.

Comment: I added the details...

Comment: @copper.hat: I don't understand the part $d(x,y)\le 2d'(x,y)$. Please explain?

Comment: @copper.hat: "Now suppose $x_n$ is a $d'$-Cauchy sequence, and choose $N$ such that if $m,n \ge N$, then $d'(x_n,x_m) \le {1 \over 2}$. Then for $m,n \ge N$, we have
$d(x,y) \le  2 d'(x,y)$" How $d(x,y) \le  2 d'(x,y)$? or should I ask this on the site?

Comment: @Sucre: Suppose $f:[0,\infty] \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = {x \over 1-x}$. Show that if $x \le {1 \over 2}$ then $f(x) \le 2x$. We have $d(x,y) = f(d'(x,y))$, so when $d'(x,y) \le {1 \over 2}$ then $d(x,y) \le 2 d'(x,y)$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function given by $f(x)= \frac{x}{x+1}$ and study its graph paying attention to:

- The boundedness of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}_{0}^{+}$
- The monotonicity of $f$
- The concavity of $f$

With this in mind convince yourself about these equalities of balls:

- $B(x_0,r) = B '(x_0, \frac{r}{1+r})$ for all $x_0$ in $X$ and $0 \leq r$
- $B'(x_0,\rho) = B(x_0, \frac{\rho}{1-\rho})$ for all $x_0$ in $X$ and
  $0 \leq \rho < 1$

Because of these equalities the two metrics define the same balls, hence the same open sets, hence the same topologies. Now observe that $\frac{r}{1+r} \rightarrow 0$ when $r \rightarrow 0$ and that $\frac{\rho}{1-\rho} \rightarrow 0$ when $\rho \rightarrow 0$. It follows that $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ are metric spaces with the same underlying topology and $(X,d)$ is complete if and only if $(X,d')$ is.

Comment: This is not quite true, the metric $d'(x,y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y|$ generates the same topology as $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, but the sequence $x_n = n$ is Cauchy in $d'$ but not in $d$.

Comment: The fact that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent does *not* imply that one is complete iff the other is.

Comment: I'll fix it in a moment.

Comment: Fixed, I think.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $d(x,y)\ge\epsilon$, then

$$d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}=1-\frac1{1+d(x,y)}\ge 1-\frac1{1+\epsilon}=\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}\;.$$

If $d'(x,y)\ge\epsilon$, then $\epsilon<1$, and

$$\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\ge\epsilon\;,$$

so $d(x,y)\ge\epsilon+\epsilon d(x,y)$, and

$$d(x,y)\ge\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}\;.$$

Use these to show that if a sequence is not Cauchy in one metric, then it’s not Cauchy in the other metric, and use the fact (that I suspect you’ve already proved) that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent.